# OmniAuth, Twitter + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use OmniAuth in my Rails app, to allow users to sign in with Twitter.
In my Twitter app's settings in a Callback URL field I have:

```
127.0.0.1:3000/users/auth/twitter/callback
```

(I was following a tutorial). I have a question: why it works even in production, on Heroku? I thought I will have to change it to my Heroku address. But it works even after deploying to Heroku. I'm not complaining, but I want to understand it completely :)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's working because you're logging in to the Heroku version from your development system where your dev rails server `rails s` is still running, so it's just pointing back from your browser to your local instance of your app?  Try logging in from a different machine or turning off your development server and see if it still works?

Edit: I'm new at this stuff too so I am probably off, but how I understand the authentication flow, when you specify your callback URL on our Twitter app settings, after the user is redirected to Twitter and grants access to your app, twitter just adds the authentication token info as a parameter to the callback URL that you provided and redirects the user there. So my guess is that it's just sending you back to the local instance of your app.